# Generating Different Random Numbers in ExcelSpreadsheet using For Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am trying to generate specific random numbers in particular cells.
I have written the code. But when I run it, the output is the same value in each cell. But I want different values in each cell for different values of 'j' as the For Loop proceeds. Please correct my code to get the desired output. Thanks in advance.

VBA Code is as follows :

```
Sub BB()

Dim W(1 To 10) As Double
Dim W0 As Double, Wn As Double
Dim j As Integer

W0 = 0

Wn = (10) ^ 0.5 * Cells(1, 1).Value

For j = 1 To 10

    W(j) = Application.NormInv(Rnd(), Wn * j, Wn * j ^ 2 + W0)

Next j

Sheets("BB").Range("B1:B10").Value = W()

End Sub
```

Comment: @RBarry I have written  Application.NormInv(Rnd(), Wn * j, Wn * j ^ 2 + W0).. Where in the beginning. can you please be specific what you are asking me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the last line.  Change it to:

```
Sheets("BB").Range("B2:B9").Value = Application.Transpose(W)
```

The array you are filling is horizontal.  To turn it vertical it must be transposed.  This works on smaller arrays, there is a limit to the number that can be transposed.  After that you would need to do it with a loop.

Comment: @PankajMani Glad I could help.

Comment: But what do you mean by - "there is limit.....after that...you need.....with a loop ?

Comment: @PankajMani If you were doing an array with more than 64,000 items it would not work. it you do this the you would need to use a 2 dimension array and put every thing in the second dimension. Seeing as you are not going to reach the 64000 mark it is not something to worry about

Comment: .Ok. I dont think I need to cross 64000 items in near future.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Randomize" to your sub. It will shuffle vba random engine.

```
Sub BB()
 Randomize
...
End sub
```

Comment: Using Randomize also generates the same value in each cell but when I add Transpose as suggested above it works even without or with Randomize?